# @ Hostname not being overridden by other A record?

Tags: dns, tumblr

My domain's `A` records are:

```
Host:           Points to:
@               66.6.44.4
experiments     188.121.46.1
```

The `@` points to my Tumblr blog, and the `experiments` subdomain points to my hosting.

The problem I'm having is, `experiments.example.com` is somehow redirecting (`curl` shows that it's a 301) to `example.com/experiments/`. I've checked http://whatsmydns.net and it too confirms that those hosts point to those IPs.

How is this happening? I've emptied my DNS cache a few times so I don't think it's that. Where is that redirect coming from?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to ask this question in http://superuser.com or http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Actually this is not a DNS problem, but a webserver issue.**

**Your webserver** running at `http://experiments.example.com` **redirects** to `http://example.com/experiments/`. So check your Webserver configuration to find any redirect directives.

**DNS only resolves names to IP addresses.** It does not redirect HTTP requests.

HTTP is a protocol. With `http://experiments.example.com` you connect to a server `experiments.example.com` (IP 192.0.2.46) on port 80 where your webserver listens, accepts the request and redirects it to `http://example.com/experiments/` and your broswer follows this redirect querying host *example.com* (IP 203.0.113.42) on port 80 to `GET /experiments/` there.

Comment: Actually your browser gets a `301 Moved Permanently` redirect. Followed by a `404 Not Found` on the server you got redirected to.